# Is it possible to define a custom tracking mechanism with the Microsoft sync framework?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I am currently evaluating the Microsoft sync framework as a possible solution to sync data between two SQL databases. The examples I have seen so far rely on "tracking tables" containing the information used to track changes to be synced, with triggers on the main tables to keep them up to date.

My database already contains lots of this information (for an existing feature of the software), so it would be good to make use of that instead of having to migrate it all to the new tracking tables. I also don't like the ideas of doubling-up each table into a data table and a tracking table, and adding three triggers to each table - that sounds like it is likely to be a performance issue?

Is there any way of customising the tracking mechanism used by the sync framework (ie. the way in which changes are tracked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible to write your own logic to track changes and use them. For eg. one of the db syncproviders I have used, requires that you should define selectincrementalinsert command. Now which table(s) that data comes from and how you filter out the latest records is immaterial - you just need to define a query or an sp that gives you this data. This applies to all the other incremental sps (which deal with the change tracking)

Along with that you need an anchor value to define when the last sync has happened. I think there is no point in avoiding this one, since this is used exclusively for synchronization and your existing tracking tables will not contain a replacement for this.

Comment: Are you using a `SyncAdapter`? I asked this [same question on the MS forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/synclab/thread/2335abd9-bc91-4ede-b515-67a39d000967) for the 4.0 CTP of the Sync Framework and got the response that SyncAdapters are obsolete in the latest version.

Comment: I am using SyncAdapter. Although they say there is not much development going on, it does work quite fine the way it is and it is not deprecated as such. It even works with non-sql server databases, so I don't see any reason not to use it. MS probably wants to promote sql server 2008 and thats natural for them.

Comment: Do you know where i can find sample code - to start learning on this Microsoft SyncFramework - i have tried the msdn - but it seems that their sample code doesn't compile.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=sync&ReleaseId=1200 and other links from this page. Some examples say that they are deprecated, but going through all will give you an idea about the basics of sync framework as well.